# calculate cycle per instruction CPI

Tags: pipeline

A program consists of 40% ALU (r-type) instructions, 20% stores, 20% memory reads and 10% jumps.  40% of the values read from memory are used in the next instruction.
Assuming this is a large program, what is the CPI?
 answer=1.4 Can anyone explain this please?

Comment: 40% + 20% + 20% + 10% = 90% — what is the remaining 10% of instructions?

Comment: Assuming the instruction can take either 1 or 2 cycles, 40% of all instructions must take 2 cycles and remaining 60% must take 1 cycle to make an average of 1.4.